# pyhook installing in python 3.7 "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook "

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyhook

I tried to download pyhook with pip but im getting the error: "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyhook "

I've tried to download it from 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook but it still doesn't seem to work.
What may be the problem ?

Comment: pip would not work for this packages because it's not available on pypi.org. The page doesn't give any installation command
https://pypi.org/project/pyHook/

Comment: Have you tried downloading the .whl file and trying pip install <filename>.whl

Comment: I tried, and it gives me the error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in ..." @MuhammadAsif

Comment: Please share a detailed log of this error with the question, that'd be helpful

Comment: The www.lfd.uci.edu [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) says there's a maintained fork of it named [PyWinHook](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinhook). Here's the pypi link for [pyWinhook](https://pypi.org/project/pyWinhook/), and the installation is `pip install pyWinhook`.